# Dynamics CRM 2013 - User in different business unit cannot see certain entities on nav bar

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2013

OK a little bit of background first.  The organisation is set up with 7 users with 3 business units.  Each of these business units are inherited from a parent so they should have the same security priviledges etc.  Each business unit has a corresponding team (with no security roles attached).  Each user has been assigned the same security role.

The problem is that a user in one of the business units is unable to see Cases in the main navigation bar.  I have checked that the security roles are correctly configured to be able to create/read/update/delete Cases, however I cannot see any options for hiding entities from the main nav bar.  Is there another setting somewhere that controls this?  How can I get the Case options to appear again for this one user?

Comment: are the 3 BUs children of the org? are any of the other 6 (who I assume work correctly, in the same BU as the 1 that doesn't? Do all 7 have the same set of security roles directly associated their user?

Comment: All 3 BU's are indeed children of the organisation.  The other 6 are in different BU's to the user that is having these issues.  Security Roles have been assigned directly to all users, and they all use the same security role.

Comment: first thing I'd try is creating another user in the same BU as the problem user, with identical security. If the new user has the same issue, it points to something about the BU setup

Answer (score 1):

Seeing the comments above, it seems that you may have an issue whereby the Security Role acts differently depending on the Business Unit that the user is in. This is most likely to happen when one of your privileges is set to Parent:Child Business Units, which actually means a User in a Parent BU can see records in the Child BU - The navigation does not work in the reverse direction (Child to Parent). To enable this transparency, the user in the lower Business Unit would need Organizational level privileges to see data such as Contacts & Cases in the higher up BUs.

Hope this helps.
Aaron